# Create a link inside xml in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I have an xml String as:

```
var txt, parser, xmlDoc;
        txt = "<Employees xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\"><Employee>"
                + "<ID xlink:type=\"simple\">1</ID>"
                + "<Name>Employee1</Name>"
                + "<Description>Employee1 Description</Description>"
                + "</Employee>"
                + "<Employee>"
                + "<ID xlink:type=\"simple\">2</ID>"
                + "<Name>Employee2</Name>"
                + "<Description>Employee2 Description</Description>"
                + "</Employee></Employees>";

var htmlString = htmlEntities(txt);
        document.getElementById('empDetails').innerHTML = htmlString;
        alert("HTML formatted display: \n" + htmlString);

        function htmlEntities(str) {
            var htmlString = String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g,
                    '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
            return htmlString;
        }
```

Where my empDetails is a **p** tag as:

```
<p id="empDetails"></p>
```

now i am able to show xml inside this **p** tag.
The problem is that i want to show a hyperlink on the id's of the printed xml.
So when the xml is printed in the **p** tag it should show a hyperlink on the id node. i tried using xlink as you can see but it's of no use.

How to achieve this. Looking forward to your answers. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

y don't you provide the `xlink:href` attribute in the ID tag?